# Macbook Air no OS, no internet recovery, bootable USB not working

Tags: macbook-pro

I was trying to update my MacBook air to Mojave but there was some error. When I searched online, I found that a system file got deleted while updating on some systems and this had happened to me.

Troubleshooting leads to more problems and now the MacBook is not starting up and shows a question mark folder.

Now the MacBook has no Operating System.

Mac Utilities is also not working.

Internet Recovery also not working.

The last option left was a bootable USB. This USB is not being detected on the disk selection screen(after holding down the option key).

Only bootable USB with macOS is not being detected. Ubuntu, Windows and Linux bootable USBs are detected.

Comment: what is the model of Macbook Air do you have and also mention the year of the model.

Comment: It sounds like you have a hardware issue and not a software one.  You don’t need an OS at all to launch internet recovery or use a bootable USB.  Try running [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) and post what the results are